# What is $\operatorname{syt}$?

Tags: functions, notation

I came across the following definition of the set on [this web page](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Euler%27s_totient_function)

[image]

But what is $\operatorname{syt}$?

Comment: Can you give context for this definition?  Where did you see it originally?

Comment: See the edit submitted one second after your comment ;)

Comment: This only shows the page I was reading ;(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit of poking around, I found the same result as @SiongthyeGoh, but not from a mathematical P.O.V:

From [The Census of Mathematical Notations](http://notations.hoplahup.net/Census/CD-arith1/gcd):

> On the Helsinki University of Technology, Department of Mathematics website, we find that they use **syt** instead of $\gcd$, and it is called '**Suurin yhteinen tekijä**' in a Finnish context.
>
> Also find **syt** in Wikipedia. Usually at university level notation (a,b) is used for greatest common divisor of numbers a and b instead of letter combination syt. For example see Lecture notes by Pentti Haukkanen at University of Tampere.

For further reference, here is [the link](https://matta.hut.fi/matta2/isom/html/alkutekj3.html) to the webpage quoted. As you might expect, it supposedly (I don't speak Finnish) translates somewhat literally to..."greatest common divisor"

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is just a typo. syt is just gcd.

\begin{align*}
A_d &= \left\{ x: 1 \leq x \leq n\text{ and } gcd(x,n)=d \right\}\\
&= \left\{ dx': 1 \leq x' \leq n/d \text{ and } gcd(dx',n)=d \right\}\\
&= \left\{ dx': 1 \leq x' \leq n/d \text{ and } gcd(x',n/d)=1 \right\}.\\
\end{align*}

We can see that the set above have the same cardinality with the set

$$A_d'=\left\{ x: 1 \leq x \leq n/d \text{ and } gcd(x,n/d)=1 \right\}.$$